# What is Matrix's mapPoints() method used for? What does it do?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, matrix

The Android Developer's documentation for Matrix's mapPoints() method says,

> Apply this matrix to the array of 2D points specified by src, and write the transformed points into the array of points specified by dst. The two arrays represent their "points" as pairs of floats [x, y].

I quite don't get it. What does it actually do? I searched for an explanation for this method on the internet but didn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

[Matrix.mapPoints](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix#mapPoints(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)) is to be used for applying the matrix transform(=[2D affine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#In_the_plane), in general) to the points at once as follows.

[image: Math behind Matrix.mapPoints and Matrix.mapVectors]

**Minimal code for testing mapPoints.**

```
// Matrix components
val mc = floatArrayOf(
    1F, 2F, 3F,
    10F, 20F, 30F,
    0F, 0F, 1F
)

val m = Matrix()
m.setValues(mc)

val srcPoint = floatArrayOf(1F, 2F) // [0]=x [1]=y
val dstPoint = FloatArray(2)

m.mapPoints(dstPoint, srcPoint)

Log.i("MapPoints", dstPoint.joinToString { it.toString() }) // 8.0, 80.0

// Algebraic expression equivalent to the mapPoints() above

dstPoint[0] = mc[Matrix.MSCALE_X] * srcPoint[0] +
        mc[Matrix.MSKEW_X] * srcPoint[1] +
        mc[Matrix.MTRANS_X]

dstPoint[1] = mc[Matrix.MSKEW_Y] * srcPoint[0] +
        mc[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] * srcPoint[1] +
        mc[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]

Log.i("MapPoints", dstPoint.joinToString { it.toString() }) // 8.0, 80.0
```